# Convert List to typeof UnderlyingSystemType

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, reflection, dynamic-linq

I am currently working on code that is using [dynamic-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linq), I ran into a problem when using a `List<BaseClass>`, where the list actually contains a list of the `Person` Class.

When I execute the following code I get a `ParseException`:

```
var list = new List<BaseClass>();

list.Add(new Person
{
  FirstName = "Joe",
  Surname   = "Bloggs"
});

list.Where("FirstName == @0", "Joe");
```

And the Exception:

[image]

Please see `BaseClass` below:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Person` class:

```
public class Person : BaseClass
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Surname   { get; set; }
}
```

I can **overcome** the error by implementing the following code:

```
var list = new List<BaseClass>();

list.Add(new Person
{
  FirstName = "Joe",
  Surname   = "Bloggs"
});            

var newList = CreateListOfCorrectType<BaseClass>(list);
newList.Where("FirstName == @0", "Joe");
```

Please see `CreateListOfCorrectType<T>` method below:

```
private IList CreateListOfCorrectType<T>(
         List<T> list) 
{
  if (list.Count == 0)
  {
    return list;
  }

  var typeInfo = list.FirstOrDefault().GetType();

  var correctListType   = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeInfo.UnderlyingSystemType);
  var listOfCorrectType = (Activator.CreateInstance(correctListType)) as IList;

  list.ForEach(x => listOfCorrectType.Add(x));

  return listOfCorrectType;
}
```

My **Question** is if using the `CreateListOfCorrectType` is the best way of overcoming the issue? and if not what alternatives do I have in getting the `List<BaseClass>` to the correct Type.

I am looking to use this with existing code, and changing the existing `List<>`types are not possible. And the `CreateListOfCorrectType` method is not aware of the `Person` class.

*Please note that class names and variables are for demonstrative purposes only.*

**UPDATE**

Optimist's answer below leaded me to the solution for my issue, please see extension method used below:

```
public static IList ToDerivedListType(this IList list)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0) 
        {
            return list;
        }

        var type       = list.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault().GetType();
        var castedList = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                                           .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                                           .Invoke(null, new[] { list });

        return typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                                 .MakeGenericMethod(type)
                                 .Invoke(null, new[] { castedList }) as IList;           
    }
```

`System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast` and `MakeGenericMethod` was the key.

Comment: Try this: `list.Select(b => Convert.ChangeType(b, b.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType)).Where(...)`

Comment: @cubrr when trying your suggested code I get `No property or field 'FirstName' exists in type 'Object'`

Comment: Ah, damn. Was worrh a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the actual use cases, some things can be improved:

- runtime expenses: the `CreateListOfCorrectType` function copies all elements  into a new collection which results in unnecessary expense in case only a subset is taken out of the returned collection .
- scope of applicability of the mapping function: this could be widened to work with `IEnumerable`.
- finally, both the mapping and the filtering function can be combined into one to reduce the amount of code in consuming functions.

`System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast` and `MakeGenericMethod` can be employed to achieve that:

```
static public class Extension
{
    static public IEnumerable CastDynamic(this  IEnumerable Source, Type Type)
    {
        return
            (IEnumerable)
            typeof(Enumerable)
            .GetMethod("Cast", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
            .MakeGenericMethod(Type)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { Source });
    }

    static public IEnumerable CastToFirstType(this  IEnumerable Source)
    {
        if (0 == Source.Take(1).Count())
        {
            return Source;
        }

        return CastDynamic(Source, Source.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault().GetType());
    }

    static public IEnumerable WhereCastToFirstType(this IEnumerable Source, string Predicate, params object[] values)
    {
        return Source.CastToFirstType().Where(Predicate, values);
    }
}
```

If tried to mimic the function you showed in terms of exceptions thrown. There is a difference because the casting is done after the mapping function returns.

Comment: thanks @Optimist, `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast` and `MakeGenericMethod` was the key.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the OfType linq method:

```
list.OfType<Person>().Where("FirstName == @0", "Joe");
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the `CreateListOfCorrectType` is not aware of the type 'Person' so I have to get the type dynamically.

Comment: I guess its not problem with the linq rather `list.Add` where he is adding a person to a List<BaseClass>. There wouldnt be a problem if it was declared like - `List<BaseClass> list = new List<Person>();`. I guess the OP doesnt want to declare it like that. Correct me if I am wrong @TjaartvanderWalt

Comment: Oh I see, you don't know the type beforehand.

Comment: @CarbineCoder you are correct in saying I do not want to declare it like that as I have no control over the declaration of the list.